# not looping through all items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
this.draw = function() {
    console.log(this.buttonList.length);
    for(a = 0; a < this.buttonList.length; a++) {
        console.log(this.buttonList.length, a);
        this.buttonList[a].draw();
    }
};
```

So I have this function within an object, and it's not working the way I expected it to. When I run it with the above `console.log` statements, it logs this on the console:

```
2
2 0
```

This seems to tell me that my for loop is not looping through every item on the array, and I've been scratching my head over why that would be for a quite a while now. Does anyone know why it's only performing the action for a = 0?

edit: I don't know if this makes a difference, but this function is called about 60 times every second.

Comment: Maybe because the `button` object hasn't got a function called `draw` and stops execution there.

Comment: I see that a is a global variable. It is probably re-set somewhere else.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen As OP obviously looks at the console, he would have noticed it.

Comment: this.buttonList.length is undefined?

Comment: @dystroy: I agree he SHOULD have noticed such an error. But it's not 100% clear.

Comment: Both @SaniHuttunen and @dystroy are potentially correct. `a` could definitely be getting overwritten (always declare variables with `var`!). Also, if each element of `buttonList` doesn't have a `draw` method, execution would stop there at the first iteration.

Comment: Another observation: What is `this` in `this.draw`? If it's an element of the objects in `buttonList` then you'd have a stackoverflow due to infinite recursion. Mentioning this since you say it's called 60 times a second with which you can mean that you noticed it's called 60 times a second or you intentionally call it 60 times a second. I'm guessing the former.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `var` would probably fix it :

```
this.draw = function() {
    console.log(this.buttonList.length);
    for(var a = 0; a < this.buttonList.length; a++) {
        console.log(this.buttonList.length, a);
        this.buttonList[a].draw();
    }
};
```

There's very probably another point of your code where you change `a`. You should be careful with the variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

There are atleast three possibilities for the behavior:

1. `a` is overwritten (as per `dystroys` answer).
2. All elements in `buttonList` don't have a `draw` function.
3. `this` in the function definition of `draw` is an element in the `buttonList`.

The first two possibilities are easy to fix but the third one depends on what your intentions are, i.e. what do you wish to accomplish. To fix it we need more information.

Any one of the three possibilities (or combinations of the possibilities) could account for the behavior.

The first possibility is explained by `dystroy`.

The second possibility will stop excecution if an element doesn't have a `draw` function. In this case it seems to be the first element.

The third possibility will render in a stack overflow due to infinite recursion. The `draw` function is called over and over again just logging to console `2` then `2 0` until all the stack is consumed at which point the execution stops.

Comment: Voi kiitos huolellisesta vastauksestasi! Right after I fixed the problem, a new one came up, where it froze up, and possibility #3 might help me figure out the problem. Kummallista, että itseasiassa tunnen jotakuta SaMi Huttusta. ö !

Comment: Ole hyvä! ;) Please update your question or even better ask a new question with details of your new problem.